# AZ module seems to keep breaking in powershell with a message about import-module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to use azure keyvault in a powershell script that is used by a github action. HEre is an example of my code, which worked at least once earlier today

```
$TenantID = my_tenant_id"
$securePassword = "passowrd_for_key_vault_account" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "my_application_id", $securePassword

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -TenantID $TenantID
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following error

```
The 'Connect-AzAccount' command was found in the module 'Az.Accounts', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Accounts'.
```

When I run Import-Module Az.Accounts I get

```
Import-Module: Assembly with same name is already loaded
```

I am installing & Importing the module earlier in my code with the following

```
   Install-Module -Name Az -scope currentuser -force -AllowClobber
   Import-Module Az
```

I tried to connect an azure service account
I was expecting it to log in and continue on to pull information from key vault

Comment: Why are you installing a cmdlet that is already installed?  You only install a cmdlet once, not every time you run the powershell script.

Comment: Could you send if you have other modules like PatnerCenter or Azure AD and the version of Azure AD?

Comment: @grzy7316x , use this command for import module & Let me know.:
Import-Module az -Scope Local

Comment: @jdweng - I am installing it repeatedly because this script is meant to run on a github runner, which only exists during the run of the deployment process.

Comment: Then check if it exists and drop so you do not get error.

Answer (score 1):

> AZ module seems to keep breaking in powershell with a message about import-module:

This is usually the case if you have an `AzureRM` module installed in addition to the `Az` modules in PowerShell library. Even with the `Az/Az.Accounts` module installed, there may be issues with PowerShell if `AzureRM` was previously installed.

As a result, use this command to ***uninstall*** the `AzureRM` module.

```
uninstall-AzureRM
```

***After executing it, I tried connecting*** `Az account` ***and it worked successfully.***

```
$TenantID = "tenant_ID"
$securePassword = "secret/password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "AppID", $securePassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -TenantID $TenantID
```

***Output:***

[image]

Note:

1. *Make sure that update to the latest versions of the required modules when any new releases are there using command:*

```
update-module
```

2. *To check the current running version use this command with the required module name:*

```
 get-module Az.accounts
```

[image]

3. *Check the available modules list by using:*

```
get-module -ListAvailable
```

[image]